# Coalesce on properties of object to return null or object?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create an extension that would allow me to check the property of an object.  If the property doesn't equal a value that I need the property to equal (or multiple properties), it will return a null object.  If it does equal, it will return the same object.  My project there are a TON of places this has to be done on multiple classes and properties, so as little as code as possible (other than the extension of supporting code).

For instance, I have a class with an Age property.  Any age over 55 but less than 60, will return null.  Any age under 55 and above 60, will return the object.

`// Set the object of person to null, so we can error detect off of it later
var person = person.SOMEEXTNAME(p => p.Age >= 55 && p.Age <= 60);`

// Returns a valid object of PERSON
var person = person.SOMEEXTNAME(p => p.Age < 55 || p.Age > 60);

I've tried a couple different approaches, but can't seem to nail it down.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
   public static T NullOrDefaultIfFalse<T>(this T self, Func<T,bool> conditionFunc)
   {
       return conditionFunc(self) ? self : default(T);
   }
```

Usage:

```
   var person = person.NullOrDefaultIfFalse(p => p.Age < 55 || p.Age > 60); //Takes advantage of type parameter inference
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static TProperty? If<TProperty>(this TProperty propValue, Func<TProperty,Boolean> validator) {

    return propValue != default(TProperty) && validator( propValue ) ?
        propValue : default(TProperty);
}
```

this could be used like so:

```
class Person {
    public Int32 Age;
}

////

Person p = new Person() { Age = 25; }
Int32? age = p.Age.If( pv => pv < 55 && pv > 60 );
```

Note that handling both reference-types and value-types makes it a bit more complicated. If you added generic type constraints you could make it easier to follow.